# Create a Enterprise using a service account

Tags: android-management-api

Here in my company we use G-suite, and it's not possible to create enterprises using our accounts. So, it's possible to create enterprises using services accounts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t use a service account to create enterprises. Service accounts are used to authorize API access when you build a server-based EMM solution.

To create an enterprise you need a **Gmail** account that's not already associated with an enterprise. I suggest checking this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-enterprise) for more information.